# d2: What are semantics of opDot?

Tags: d

I've met several mentions about opDot method, that allows to overload member access aka dot operator, but official documentation for it is missing. It's surely not dropped out, as std.typecons.Unique makes use of it.

Does anybody know, how opDot can be used, and why there is no documentation about it?

Comment: Try this: http://www.digitalmars.com/d/archives/digitalmars/D/learn/how_to_use_opdot_14509.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`opDot` has been [scheduled for deprecation](http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=2327). That's why it isn't documented. Don't use it. Use [`alias this`](http://dlang.org/class.html#AliasThis) instead. You can use it to alias a particular type or function to a type so that it can act like that type. e.g.

```
struct S
{
    int value;
    alias value this;
}
```

will make it so that a variable of type `S` will implicitly convert to `int` using `S`'s `value` field. You can also alias functions that way:

```
struct S
{
    int get()
    {
        return 7;
    }

    alias get this;
}
```

though that can be more limiting, since dmd does not currently support having multiple `alias this`es for a type (it should eventually though). In this case, you can then implicitly cast `S` to a an `int`, but not the reverse. Regarldess, `alias this` is intended for implementing implicit conversions.

If `alias this` isn't quite what you want, another possibility is [`opDispatch`](http://dlang.org/operatoroverloading.html). It allows you to transform what's on the right-hand side of the dot into other stuff (e.g. turn all calls to `foo` into `bar`). But, between those two, you should be able to do pretty much anything you were thinking of doing with `opDot` (and a lot more besides).